# school timetable: best database table design

Tags: mysql

I want to create a typical school timetable for each user.

**The end product should look like this:**

```
+----+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|  h | Monday  | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
+----+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|  1 | SCIENCE | MATHS   | ENGLISH   | FRENCH   | ART    |
|  2 | SCIENCE | MATHS   | ENGLISH   | FRENCH   | ART    |
|  3 |         | MUSIC   | HISTORY   | GEO      |        |
|  4 |         | MUSIC   | HISTORY   | GEO      |        |
|  5 | HEALTH  | PE      | MATHS     |          |        |
|  6 | HEALTH  | PE      | MATHS     |          |        |
|  7 |         |         |           |          |        |
|  8 |         |         |           | SCIENCE  |        |
|  9 |         |         |           | SCIENCE  |        |
| 10 |         |         | PE        |          |        |
| 11 |         |         | PE        |          |        |
+----+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Now I want to create a MySQL table for this application.

**My idea was this (but is this the best way because this table would have many many columns):**

```
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+----
| user_id | mo1 | mo2 | mo3 | mo4 | mo5 | mo6 | mo7 | mo8 | mo9 | mo10 | mo11 | tu1 | tu2 | tu3 | tu4 | tu5 | tu6 | tu7 | tu8 | tu9 | tu10 | tu11 | we1 | we2 | ...
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+----
|    ?    |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |   ?  |   ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |   ?  |   ?  |  ?  |  ?  | ...
|    ?    |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |   ?  |   ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |   ?  |   ?  |  ?  |  ?  | ...
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+----
```

In conclusion: What would be the best design of a MySQL table for a typical school timetable (with user_id)?

**UPDATE 1**

The user can input a text/subject-name for each lesson via many HTML text-fields (maybe there is also a better solution). But one important thing I forgot to say is that I have no courses-table.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should not be just one table.  You might have a table for the courses, a table for the students, and an associated table that connects the two.  The table for the student would have the student id.  The table for the course would have the course id and what dates and hour it is offered.  The associated table would have a user id and a course id, connecting each student to each course they take.  Then there are ways to query such tables to get the output you ask for here.  But the table you propose is not normalized and will give you all kinds of other headaches.

Comment: Ok this is a good solution. But one thing I forgot to say (sorry for that) is that the user can input their text/subject-name for each lesson, so there is no courses-table at all. Is there a good table-design for this?